# MySQL Even Scheduler Generic Time Expressions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get MySQL to carry out some routine tasks using the `event_scheduler` facility, which shows up in the result set returned by the `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` query.

I want to create 3 scheduled tasks: daily (at 00:00:00 AM), weekly ( on Sunday at 00:00:00 AM) and monthly (on every 1st day at 00:00:00 AM).

I know I could do that by designating a start time. Like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS do_daily $$
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
    EVENT do_daily
    ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    **STARTS '2018-10-29 00:00:00'**
DO
BEGIN
    -- Do daily chore...
END $$

DELIMITER $$
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS do_weekly $$
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
    EVENT do_weekly
    ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 WEEK
    **STARTS '2018-11-04 00:00:00'**
DO
BEGIN
    -- Do weekly chore...
END $$

DELIMITER $$
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS do_monthly $$
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
    EVENT do_monthly
    ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 WEEK
    **STARTS '2018-11-01 00:00:00'**
DO
BEGIN
    -- Do monthly chore...
END $$
```

The problem with this is that the date-times are hard-coded in the script and I'd like to make them generic so that I can run the queries later on without a worry.

In other words, when I run the query for these events, no matter what the time at the time of running may be, the `STARTS` expressions must always refer to the next "00:00:00 AM" for the daily, 'Sunday 00:00:00 AM' for the weekly and '1st day 00:00:00 AM' for the monthly routines.

Any idea how?

Comment: Am I missing something? Your current script should do exactly what you are describing with the hard coded times. (Starting times can lie in the past.)

Comment: Yes, but if I'd like to run the script a year later, I'd be referring to a previous date-time. Honestly, I have no idea what the outcome would be, but I'd still like to know if there is a way in MySQL to always refer to a certain, relative date-time.